# Equivalent of atoi for unsigned integers

Tags: c, integer-overflow, atoi

I'm doing two operations involving atoi and I'm wondering how I can do this with unsigned integers because atoi seems to convert these to signed causing a wraparound integer overflow. I want to work with 32bit unsigned integers but atoi is limiting me effectively to 31bit unsigned.

```
 if (multiplication_is_safe(atoi(argv[1]),atoi(argv[3])))
    {
     printf("%s * %s = %u \n", argv[1], argv[3], atoi(argv[1]) * atoi(argv[3]));
      return 0;
    }  else
```

Comment: `atoll`? I'm not sure if it's a standard C function though.

Comment: If code needs at least 16-bit unsigned, use `unsigned`.  If code needs at least 32-bit unsigned, use `unsigned long`.  If code needs at exactly 32-bit unsigned, use `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The simple answer is to use [`strtoul()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoul.html) instead.

The longer answer is that even if all you needed was signed 32 bit integers or were happy with 31 bits for unsigned, the `atoi()` function is a poor fit for what you appear to be doing.

As you have already noted, the [`atoi()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html) function converts a string to an integer. A normal, signed integer. However, what `atoi()` *doesn't* do is error handling. What `atoi()`'s specification says is "**If the value cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.**"

The strto*() family of functions all clearly specify how errors are handled, so you should in all cases replace `atoi()` with calls to `strtol()` (convert string to long), and in this case since you want to handle unsigned integers, you should use `strtoul()` (convert string to unsigned long).

Also note that if you want to handle larger numbers, there are the `strtoll()` and `strtoull()` functions, to convert your string to a long long or an unsigned long long. (And if you just want to handle the largest possible integral values without bothering with all that stuff in between, there's `strtoimax()` and `strtoumax()`, that return values of type `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t` respectively.)

POSIX Documentation:

- [`atoi()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html)
- [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html)
- [`strtoll()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoll.html)
- [`strtoul()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoul.html)
- [`strtoull()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoull.html)
- [`strtoimax()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoimax.html)
- [`strtoumax()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtoumax.html)

Comment: Great answer.  Love the `undefined` quote.  I hit this issue.  I put a decimal value of ~7 billion (that fit nicely into an `unsigned long long`) into  `atoi()`.  I was hoping for an error code. Instead I got the MAX value for an `unsigned long long` .  This value was 18 billion billion. 

Comment: I really like this article from Microsoft on the limits of C Data Types `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2017`

 Very relevant when dealing with `atoi` and the `int` return type.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your platform, [strtoul](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoul) is probably what you want:

> The strtoul() function converts the initial part of the string in nptr
>   to an unsigned long int value according to the given base, which must
>   be between 2 and 36 inclusive, or be the special value 0.